# using state in dangerouslySetInnerHTML react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a string about html builded by react.
I'm trying to implement render this html string through react, and looking for solution to manage state.

below is simple example.

```
const App = (props) => {
  let code = '<b>Will This Work?</b>';

  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: code} }>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to manage the state of component rendered with `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` option.

Can i get any ideas about how approach?

Comment: Please clarify question

Answer (score 0):

## What is dangerouslySetInnerHTML?

It is a way to set the children of the component (as text/html).

### Can state be used in it?

Yes state *can* be used with it; However, the innerHTML MUST be vanilla HTML, NOT JSX. An example of this can be seen below:
(click the button to change the state from text to a red div)

The way this is working is because the state can be inserted into a string literal which will then be handled as HTML encoded text.

```js
const App = (props) => {
  const [state,setState] = React.useState("something I set with state");
  
  let code = `<b>Will This Work? ${state}</b>`;

  return (
  <React.Fragment>
    <button onClick={()=>{setState("<div style=\"background-color: red; width:50px; height:50px;\"><div>")}}>Click to change state from pure text to an html element</button>
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ {__html: code} }>
    </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.querySelector('.react')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

### Should you do this?

Probably not. There is a reason it is called dangerouslySetHTML and not safelySetInnerHTML.
See more in the [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)